# One to One with attributes EF codefirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to link two models with  One to One relationship
the classes are following:

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string PublicName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\w]+(\.?[\w\d_]+)?$")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\w]+(\.?[\w\d_]+)?$")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rate> Rates { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

i searched did not but found solution for doing than ONLY with attributes. can anybody help me with that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake that you're making is that you have both tables pointing to each other as having a foreign key relationship with the other. You have to pick one table as the base table and the other as being the one that has the FK in it. If you want the `User` table to be the base then you would do the following:

On the `User` class: Remove the `[ForeignKey]` and `[InverseProperty]` attributes from `Customer`.

On the `Customer` class:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("User")]
public int Id { get; set; }

//Other fields

public virtual User User { get; set; }
```